# Google Play Developer Console : Why there is more than one device of the same model

Tags: android, google-play

On **Google Play Developer Console** > **Device compatibility** , there is  more than one device of the same model.

For example for Samsung Galaxy 7 there are more than 10 different type in the list

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The model of the device is the same in all cases - it's Samsung Galaxy S7. The difference between them is in mobile telephony operators. Many operators sell devices with preinstalled SIM-card, that's why devices have different unique codes.

For example:

1. **heroqltevzw** is for **Verizon**
2. **heroqltespr** is for **Sprint**

and so on.

Comment: In addition, there are also different models for each region and e.g. dual-sim versions of the same phone available.